# There is 10 people that pick-up random number between 1 to 20

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

There is 10 people that pick-up random number between $1$ to $20$. More then one person can pick up same number (i.e. the pick-ups are independent).

What is the probability that the minimum number of all the people is grater then $8$?
My answer is $\frac{12^{10}}{20^{10}}$, I'm right?

And where I confused is about "What is the probability that the minimum number will be **exactly** $8$?  I don't know which is right:
$$\frac{10\cdot 13^9}{20^{10}}\;\text{or}\;\left(\frac{13}{20}\right)^{10}-\left(\frac{12}{20}\right)^{10}$$ 
**Here is the conflict:**
$\frac{10\cdot 13^9}{20^{10}}$ - One person must choose $8$ so we have 10 options. then, all the others can choose a number that is $8$ or bigger: $13^9$ [from 8 to 20] and we divide it by $\Omega$.
$\left(\frac{13}{20}\right)^{10}-\left(\frac{12}{20}\right)^{10}$ - is the number of people that can pick-up a number that is equal or greater then $8$ minus the number of people the can pick up a number that is grater then $8$.

Please help to understand which is the right one...

Thank you!!

Comment: The second (the difference) is right. There is double-counting involved in the alternative you propose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer $\dfrac{12^{10}}{20^{10}}$ to the first question is right: all $10$ people must pick numbers from among the $12$ numbers greater than $8$, the probability of which is $\left(\dfrac{12}{20}\right)^{10}$.

For the second question (minimum exactly $8$), your second answer $\left(\dfrac{13}{20}\right)^{10} - \left(\dfrac{12}{20}\right)^{10}$ is right, for the reason you stated: it's the probability that the minimum is greater than $7$, minus the probability that the minimum is greater than $8$.

In your other approach, when there are multiple people with the same choice $8$ (and the minimum is still exactly $8$), you count the same possibility multiple times for each choice of which of them you focus on as the "special" person with the minimum. You can take that into account as follows: suppose the number of people who chose exactly $8$ is $k$, which means that the remaining $10-k$ people chose numbers greater than $8$. The probability of this is 
$$\binom{10}{k} \left(\frac{1}{20}\right)^{k} \left(\frac{12}{20}\right)^{10-k}$$

As all $k$ such that $1 \le k \le 10$ are possible, the probability is got by adding them up, which gives, via the binomial theorem 
$$(x+y)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k},$$ 
the same answer 
$$\left(\frac{1}{20} + \frac{12}{20}\right)^{10} - \binom{10}{0}\left(\frac{1}{20}\right)^{0} \left(\frac{12}{20}\right)^{10}$$
$$ = \left(\dfrac{13}{20}\right)^{10} - \left(\dfrac{12}{20}\right)^{10}$$
as before.

Comment: Thank you!!
Can you explain me please where I the double counting? Thank you!

Comment: @Yoar: Suppose the ten people are called A, B, C, D, ..., H, I, J. In your second approach, the particular possibility where (say) A and D both choose $8$ you'll count (at least) twice: once you'll count it saying "A chooses $8$, and all the others choose at least $8$", and once you'll count it saying "D chooses $8$, and all the others choose at least $8$". [In contrast, by fully specifying that some particular $k$ people choose $8$ and no others, we're avoiding this overcounting, though now we have to consider all possible nonempty subsets of people who choose $8$, which is what I did above.]

Comment: Thank you so much! you helped me a lot!